# Minimal DFA of L*

Tags: automata-theory

I'm learning how to minimize DFAs.

Are the number of states in the minimal DFA of L, is equal to the number of states
in the minimal DFA of L*?
I'm trying for hours to think of examples but couldn't figure it out.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Consider $L=\{a^n: n\leq 1000\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is of course no. The difference can be enormous and http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1003/94.pdf shows you just how bad, i.e., gives an upper bound and an example meeting it.